# How do I select a new random color in Python turtle?

Tags: python, python-turtle

So I'm recreating the DVD logo in turtle. I have these variables

```
r = random.randint(0,255)
g = random.randint(0,255)
b = random.randint(0,255)
```

And they work for selecting a random color once, but only once. How I get it to select another random color?
Also, I'm new I know I suck

Comment: to get a second random color, you would do that a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to call the code a second time.

For ex.

```
def get_random_color():

   r = random.randint(0,255)
   g = random.randint(0,255)
   b = random.randint(0,255)

   return (r,g,b)

color = get_random_color()
```

Whenever you call the function above you will get a new rgb value in a tuple.